# Receive POST request and edit JSON file NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, post, webix

Can't figure out on how to edit my json file after i receive a POST request from client in NodeJS.

Using webix datatable. After i update data in the table , it sends a POST request with data + operation that was made ( webix_operation=update /delete /insert ) so i thought i could do something like this :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true }));

app.post("/Page2", function (req, res) {
    var operation = req.body.webix_operation;

    if (operation == 'update') {
        fs.readFile("JSON/DB.json", "utf8", function (err, data) {
            var allData = JSON.parse(data)
            var userData = {
                "id": req.body.id,
                "data1": req.body.data1,
                "data2": req.body.data2,
                "data3": req.body.data3,
            }
            allData.push(userData);
            var newData = JSON.stringify(allData);
            fs.writeFile("JSON/DB.json", newData, "utf8");
            console.error(err.stack);
        })
        res.send();
    }
    else if (operation == 'insert') {
    }
    else if (operation == 'delete') {

    }
    else
        console.log("This operation is not supported")
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Could someone check the code and maybe figure out what i did wrong ?

Comment: What would you mean by "it doesn't work"? At first glance I see that what you implemented is an **INSERT** operation instead of update as *îf* condition says. On the other hand, if you attach your console output it would be useful to help you...

Comment: Should'nt your statement say  `allData.push(userData);` instead of  `allData.push(newData);`

Comment: @bitifet by "it doesn't work" i mean that when the POST request is being received it does nothing. Doesn't  edit/overwrite the json file. So i assume that i did something wrong or i don't understand something.

Comment: Well. I also do things wrong quite often. The matter is to know where my code stops doing what I expect and, to do so, putting *some console.log()* statements as you did usually helps. But we need to know if you saw its output and, if true, what exactly echoed out ;-)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, changed that , sadly it didn't bring anything.

Comment: @bitifet, is there any other way to do the same without using express and bodyparser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.post("/Page2", function (req, res, next) {
    var operation = req.body.webix_operation;

    if (['insert', 'update', 'delete'].indexOf(operation) == -1)
       return next(new Error('Bad request'));

    // More better use http post to insert, put to update, delete to delete
    // e.g. app.put('/page2', func) to update

    var userData = {
        id: req.body.id,
        data1: req.body.data1,
        data2: req.body.data2,
        data3: req.body.data3
    }

    if (!userData.id)
        return next(new Error('id is not set'));

    fs.readFile("JSON/DB.json", "utf8", function (err, data) {
        if (err)       
            return next(err);

        var allData;
        try {
            allData = JSON.parse(data);
        } catch(err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        // find index of element in allData
        var i = allData.reduce(function(iRes, e, iCurr) {
             return (e.id == userData.id) ? iCurr : iRes
        }, -1);

        if (i == -1 && (operation == 'update' || operation == 'delete'))
            return next(new Error(operation + ': Bad id'));


        if (operation == 'update') 
            allData[i] = userData;

        if (operation == 'delete') 
            allData.splice(i, 1);

        if (operation == 'insert') 
            allData.push(userData);

        fs.writeFile("JSON/DB.json", JSON.stringify(allData), 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err)
                return next(err);

            res.end(); 
        })      
    }); // end of readFile
});
...
app.use(function(err, req, res, next)) {
    console.log(req.url, err);
    res.end(err.message); 
}
```